# jQuery navbar scrollTop position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, but I not the best to javascript/jQuery so are there any out there who can optimize this code?

```
$(function(){
    var pos = $("header").offset().top;

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() - 10 > pos)
        {   
           $('header').addClass("filled");
        } else {
           $('header').removeClass("filled");           
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a few questions to ask about your code, before I dive in:

- Why are you storing the header's location?
- Isn't the header supposed to be on the top?
- If it is at the top, isn't it at position 0?
- If not, are you sure you don't have some funky CSS sending weird margins and paddings over the top of the page?

---

Alright, let's dig into the code!

From now on, I will assume that the header has a weird position.

---

While you're doing right in using (the equivalent of) `$(document).ready()`, you are forgetting that `jQuery.noConflict();` can be called, breaking your code.

My suggestion is to use something like this:

```
window.jQuery(function($){
    [...]
});
```

The `window.jQuery()` (or `$()`) allows you to create an alias to the jQuery object, being it passed as the first parameter.
You can read about it on https://api.jquery.com/ready/

---

As @Dan said, you are re-re-re-re-re-forcing jQuery to painfully look for the header, every time you scroll. Can you imagine how slow that is!?

I will take @Dan's suggestion and change it a bit:

```
var $header = $('header');
var threshold = 10;
var offsetTop = $header.offset().top - threshold;
```

Why I think this is better:

- The variable names have a better meaning (`$header` -> `$('header')`).
- You can re-use the `$header`, without having to look for it all the time.
- You are already storing the value you will need later on, without you having to subtract `threshold`.
- You eliminated a magic number!

---

Taking on from @Dan's suggestion, they have the following piece of code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $header.toggleClass('filled', $(this).scrollTop() - 10 > threshold);
});
```

This is a reasonable improvement, but it is still flawed.

I propose the following:

```
var $document = $(document).scroll(function(){
    $header.toggleClass('filled', $document.scrollTop() > offsetTop);
});
```

This stores and re-used the `$document` created, instead of always running a useless `$(this)`. And since I've already subtracted the magic number, there's no need to re-calculate it here.

---

I always suggest wrapping the code on a `;(function(window, undefined){ [...] })(Function('return this')());`, but I leave it for you to decide if it is worth it or not.

---

And now, all together:

```
window.jQuery(function($){
    var $header = $('header');
    var threshold = 10;
    var offsetTop = $header.offset().top - threshold;

    var $document = $(document).scroll(function(){
        $header.toggleClass('filled', $document.scrollTop() > offsetTop);
    });
});
```

Comment: very nice answer!

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is really good. Just some tiny bits you left behind.

Comment: This is a really good answer, +1. But I think you should be using camelCase instead of underscores for your variables, as most JavaScript style guides recommend.

Comment: @theonlygusti You're right. Thanks for the reminder. I really don't like it, but it is the style guidelines and I should follow them. I've edited my answer to match your tip.

Comment: Amazing answer and also you @Dan thank you all lot! I really wanna give you both a "accepted answer" but I can't so... this time I give it to Ismael.

Thanks for two amazing answer

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Thank you for recognizing my answer. While I feel happy that you've picked my answer as the accepted one, I recommend you to retract the accepted mark for, at least, a full day. If you really liked my answer, imagine what someone else may write! I could be smooshed with an over-the-top amazing answer in pure Javascript! This is my recommendation and my advice, and it has worked well for me, in the past.

Comment: Well okay make sens.  Btw the code is much faster than my original code :D

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor If you mix my code and Martijn's code, you will have the best of both worlds!

Comment: Hi again, In Google Chrome is you scroll down and reload the page, the header "offset" is been set to that position and not on the top of the page. Why?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Do you have a small example where I can see that behaviour?

Comment: Code example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Hawkon/pen/qrWyOy)

But try it on local web server, codepen reset page when reload, so you can't see the bug there

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Sorry, I only tested it today. Yes, that is absolutely normal for the scrollbar to show at the bottom. My advice is to trigger a `.scroll()` right after, just to be sure. That means, you write `var $document = $(document).scroll(function(){ [...] }).scroll();` instead of `var $document = $(document).scroll(function(){ [...] });`. That should fix it. (It won't fix the position of the scrollbar, since it isn't wrong.)

Answer (score 9):

I would write this like:

```
$(function(){

  var header = $('header');
  var threshold = header.offset().top;

  $(document).scroll(function(){
      header.toggleClass('filled', $(this).scrollTop() - 10 > threshold);
  });

});
```

Comment: that was a much better way :o

Comment: but for reason if I use toggleClass it can't find out what to do, so the class keep toggle on and off

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor, I've updated my answer, could you please check new version?

Comment: Amazing! now it works

Comment: @theonlygusti, haha, good point!

Comment: The cleanest if statement is the if statement that isn't there :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm continueing on [the answer by Dan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/155914/75854) as this might still be buggy on lower powered devices.

I suggest you use a [dethrottle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) technique. In some browsers, **the scroll event is fired *each scrolled pixel*!** This might kill performance. The before mentioned technique limits the event to every x milliseconds, dropping the need for performance:

```
// This example will trigger the event every 25ms.
$(document).scroll( $.throttle( 25, function(){
    header.toggleClass('filled', $(this).scrollTop() - 10 > threshold);
}))
```

---

In these cases I also like to add a small extra check to avoid the bigger functions. The `toggleClass()` functions isn't very heavy, but I thought it might be worth to demo:

```
var hasPassedThreshold = false;
$(document).scroll( $.throttle( 25, function(){
    var scrolledPastThreshold = $(this).scrollTop() - 10 > threshold;

    if( !hasPassedThreshold && scrolledPastThreshold ){
        header.addClass('filled');
    }else if( hasPassedThreshold && !scrolledPastThreshold ){
        header.removeClass('filled');
    }
    hasPassedThreshold = scrolledPastThreshold ;
}));
```

In this example it *might* give a small performance boost, but in case you start adding more functionallity on the if/else, this will lighten the load.